# Oracle alter index/rebuild

Tags: oracle, indexing, rebuild

If I rebuild an unusable index using `alter index x rebuild`, will the execution plan for any SQL that used that index previously be re-evaluated?

I know that the statistics are re-calculated as part of the rebuild in the DB version I'm using - Oracle 10.2.0.4.0.

I don't want to use the dbms_stats package to force the issue on this, seeing as I've already got fresh stats!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

since the index is currently unusable, no SQL query uses the index. When you collect statistics (either through a rebuild or the `dbms_stats` package), all statements against the base table will be reparsed (hard-parse) next time they are submitted. Plans may change due to the stats update.

Rebuilding an unusable index will therefore make it visible and usable by all statements, even those that have been previously parsed.

Comment: Hi Vincent, that's what I'd both suspected and wanted to hear from someone else! Thanks for that!